# Multiplying of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=0$. Prove that there exists a decreasing sequence of positive numbers $(y_n)$ such that series $\sum y_n$ diverges and $\sum x_ny_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a sequence $(i_n)$ of indices such that $nx_k<1$ for all $k>i_n$ (especially we may set $i_0=0$). We may assume wlog. that the sequence gets sparser and sparser, i.e. that $i_{n+1}-i_n\ge i_n-i_{n-1}$ for all $n\ge 1$.
Now let 
$$y_k=\frac1{(i_n-i_{n-1})n}\qquad\text{if }i_{n-1}<k\le i_n.$$
Then $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty y_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=i_{n-1}+1}^{i_n}y_k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1n=\infty $$
whereas 
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_ky_k&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=i_{n-1}+1}^{i_n}x_ky_k\\&<\sum_{n=1}^{i_1}x_ky_k+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n-1}\sum_{k=i_{n-1}+1}^{i_n}y_k\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{i_1}x_ky_k+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n(n-1)}\\&=1+\sum_{n=1}^{i_1}x_ky_k.\end{align}$$

The sequence $y_k$ may not be *strictly* decreasing, but that can  be easily adapted.